# How to process CIFilter using CPU instead of GPU?

Tags: image-processing, cpu, gpu, core-image

Does anyone know how to tell core image to process a CIImage through a CIFilter using the CPU instead of the GPU? I need to process some very large images and I get strange results using the GPU. I don't care how long it takes to CPU will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

**kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer** is key here:

```
+ (CIContext*)coreContextFor:(NSGraphicsContext *)context forceSoftware:(BOOL)forceSoftware
{
    //CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSDictionary *contextOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    (id)colorSpace, kCIContextWorkingColorSpace,
                                    (id)colorSpace, kCIContextOutputColorSpace,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:forceSoftware], kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer,
                                    nil];
    CIContext* result = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:(CGContext *)[context graphicsPort] options:contextOptions];
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return result;
}
```

Rendering in software more (CPU) solves some issues, but... Performance penalty is so strong on modern machines that I can't say it is solution. I use CoreImage in my apps and I always render with GPU on-screen while forced CPU is used for saving only. I have noticed that CPU rendering is a bit more accurate on my test hardwares, and saving filtered image is a long process, I can sacrifice the speed here.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a shot. What I had tried was very similar but it never seemed to work correctly (it always ran on the GPU instead).

Comment: // create a CIContext that allows the user to specify that the image is rendered using the CPU
- (CIContext *)CPUonlyCIContextFromCGContext:(CGContextRef)cgContext withFlag:(BOOL)flag
{
 NSDictionary * contextOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [NSNumber numberWithBool: flag],kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer,nil];
 
 return [CIContext contextWithCGContext:cgContext options: contextOptions];
}

Comment: Sorry... I have no idea how to specify that a comment is a code snippet.

Comment: How do you use it? It works just fine. Get a NSGraphicsContext* where you are going to render a CIImage, get an appropriate CIContext with the function above and call CIContext methods to draw the image. That's regular way to render on CPU with CoreImage, it's covered in Apple docs and it should work just fine

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift version :

```
func coreContextFor(context : CGContext,forceSoftware force : Bool) -> CIContext {
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let options : [String:AnyObject] = [
        kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: colorSpace!,
        kCIContextOutputColorSpace : colorSpace!,
        kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : NSNumber(bool: force)
    ]

    return CIContext(CGContext: context, options: options)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but you always can re-write CIkernel as function which operates on pixel RGB value, and after that apply that function in a loop on `unsigned char []` data of image and convert result to CIImage.